# Como borrar el favicon de la pestaña de React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

estoy haciendo un proyecto en reactapp, pero no puedo eliminar el icono de react que esta en la pestaña

Comment: Asumo que te refieres al favicon. Puedes cambiarlo desde public/index.html

Comment: lo mismo quiero hacer yo pero en el index.html no carga ningun favicon ni nada @nashvent

Comment: ya trate de hacerlo pero no me carga tampoco

Comment: Lo carga en el manifest.json. Pero opcionalmente tu puedes agregarlo de forma manual.

Comment: Si te refieres al icono que carga cuando se guarda la pagina en el dispositivo se configura en el manifest.json. El favicon se encuentra de la siguiente forma "<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />". Para visualizar los cambios recomiendo limpiar tu memoria cache o ver la pagina desde incognito

Answer (score 0):

para que puedas cambiar el icono de la pestaña del HTML te recomiendo que primero conviertas el formato de tu imagen en formato ICO, luego ponle de nombre "favicon" y cópialo en la carpeta "public" de tu proyecto , y listo veras el cambio.